# python - add name of each group above each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with samples listed by row and attributes listed as columns. 
I'm using python to group samples by one or more attributes and using xlsxwriter to export.
Is there a way to auto insert the title of each grouping in the row above the group?

```
type1 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
t1 = result.loc[df['Name'].isin(type1)]

type2 = ['b','f']
t2 = result.loc[df['Name'].isin(type2)]

group_by_type = [t1, t2]
```

Edit

```
      Attribute1         Attribute2          Attribute3  Calculation1
0              1.565417  102.975496                    a -0.348246
1              1.577817  129.019182                    b -0.984943
2              1.577817  145.013103                    c -0.624412
3              1.594367  158.924852                    d -0.701562
4              1.586100  159.029720                    e -0.436547
5              1.594367  160.920870                    f -0.664863
6              1.586100  161.045205                    g  0.856694
7              1.598500  204.981242                    h -0.547259
8              1.619200  173.009131                    i -0.583041
9              1.623333  175.024768                    j -0.640267

type1 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
t1 = result.loc[df['Attribute3'].isin(type1)]

type2 = ['b','f']
t2 = result.loc[df['Attribute3'].isin(type2)]

titles = ['title1', 'title2']

result2 = pd.concat([t1, t2], keys=titles, axis=0)

print(result2[0:10])

             Attribute1         Attribute2          Attribute3  Calculation1
title1 0              1.565417  102.975496                    a -0.348246
       2              1.577817  145.013103                    c -0.624412
       4              1.586100  159.029720                    e -0.436547
title2 1              1.577817  129.019182                    b -0.984943
       5              1.594367  160.920870                    f -0.664863
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat` with the `keys` argument:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 3)), columns=list('DEF'))

titles = ['first', 'second']
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=titles, axis=1)

  first       second      
      A  B  C      D  E  F
0     5  0  3      4  7  6
1     3  7  9      8  8  1
2     3  5  2      6  7  7
```

Comment: Thanks! I made axis=0 so my list wouldn't expand left to right. But, in my xlsxwriter, i had index=False and that removed the title names, which were in column A. Is there a way for me to remove the index (or at least not have it export to my excel) while keeping the group titles?

Comment: @user3479562 What if you tried something like `pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=titles, axis=1).T.to_csv('file.csv', header=False)`?

Comment: The header=false removed the top row, but kept the index. Back to my original question:  `type1 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
t1 = result.loc[df['attribute'].isin(type1)]`  `titles = ['title1', 'title2']'  'result2 = pd.concat([t1, t2], keys=titles, axis=0)`  Instead of manually defining the order of the titles, Is there a way to pull the name of the group from `isin(type1)`? Because if I re-order the groups, I have to manually re-do "titles".

Comment: @user3479562 Perhaps you can provide a [mcve], showing some rows of your data in your question pasted as text into the post... I can provide a more concrete solution that way.

Comment: I added more info. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user3479562 almost there... One last thing, what is the format you want it to be saved in? How should the titles orient, etc

Comment: The titles on the left (as in my edit) or each title on the row above each group would be nice. But I'm not sure what would be easiest to read. I would save this as an excel file and I'm currently using xlsxwriter to format the output with conditional formatting. right now, i'm hiding the index column by setting the column width to 0.1.  it's my first foray into python and i think i'm just missing some options/concepts, which I want to learn.

Comment: I was able to reduce the isin to `t1 = result.loc[df['attribute'].isin(['a', 'c', 'e'])]`. Was there a way to include a 'title' within 't1' to more easily use the 'keys' argument?